# Mockito.when calling with real object return null, must use any()

Tags: java, testing, mockito

When I unit test with a mock `@Service`, I notice that in the `Mockito.when()` statement, when I save the real object, I get `null` as return; and I have to use `any()`.

So, instead of using:

```
@Mock
private BinInfoService service;
...  
@Test
public void testSave() {
    SomeBean bean = new SomeBean();
    Mockito.when(service.saveBinInfo(bean).thenReturn(bean);
}
```

I have to use:

```
Mockito.when(service.saveBinInfo(Mockito.any(SomeBean.class))).thenReturn(bean);
```

The first form returns `null`. While the second form returns the saved entity.

Why?

EDIT:

Sorry actually I am not instantiate the object like above. I used two other ways. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I just found why. The description of the question was misleading so I have to note it.

There are two cases.

1. In one method, I save the entity with mocked Rest calls, passing the entity as serialized json in as argument. I guess that when doing it the context will create new object every time and the memory address is distinct.
2. In another method, I save an entity declared as a private field, and the instantiation code method is annotated with `@Before`. So before every test it will be created once, therefore the memory address is distinct, again.

Comment: Usually, "OP"refers to the Original Poster and not to the question. It looks a weird saying that you were misleading, I can suggest to change the reference to "the question

Comment: I thought it was original post. haha.

Answer (score 1):

From https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers

> "Mockito verifies argument values in natural java style: by using an equals() method"

Probable your bean doesn't have an equals method implemented, so it returns null because a new bean is not equals to another by the default implementation.
The matcher, on the other hand, allows any bean of that class, so it always returns the value.

Comment: Cannot affirm. When I add the `equals()` and `hashCode()` method, it still cannot pass.

Comment: Have you checked if two new instances of SomeBean are equal when you implemented the method?

Comment: Yes I did; that part of assertion passes.